# Prevent multi submit PHP

Tags: php, forms, submit

I am seeking a way to prevent multi form submit. I have a form, for example chat.php and its POST action on different file, eg submitter.php.

I've tried to implement the solution with the unique token using $_SESSION.
chat had a unique $_SESSION[token] and submitter had the if $_POST[token]==$_SESSION[token]
My problem is that it didn't work if I had multiple windows opened. 
Guess the application is a chat script where users can chat on multiple windows, like chat.php?user=5, chat.php?user=10 etc)

If users had one window opened, that worked perfectly.

Any ideas?

Code as requested....

chat.php

```
$_SESSION['token'] = md5(session_id() . microtime());
```

submitter.php

```
if($_POST['submg'] == "1") {
    if ($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token']) {
     // do stuff
    }
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
}
```

Comment: Could you post some php code?

Comment: I don't know if code will help you but here it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SESSION` is going to be shared across all open browser windows on a machine. So, if you opened up Firefox, and logged in, every other Firefox window you have open is also logged into that service. What you likely want is a token *in the page* that gets submitted along with each request (much like a *CSRF token*) that is unique to the *instance of the page*. Then, a combination of the `$_SESSION` variable and the token can be used to identify a particular browser within a particular session.

Edit: Example below.

```
<?php
session_start();
$instance = null;

if (! array_key_exists('token', $_SESSION)) {
    $_SESSION['token'] = md5(time() . 'salt value');
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $instance = $_POST['instance'];
} else {
    $instance = md5(time() . 'some other salt value');
}
?>
<p>You are session <?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>, instance <?php echo $instance; ?></p>
<form method="POST" action="">
    <button type="submit" name="instance" value="<?php echo $instance; ?>">Submit</button>
</form>
```

One other thing you could do is use encryption or one-way hashing in order to mask, say, a username. So you would pass an encrypted username as your "instance" field, and then decrypt it on the back end (using the session token and instance) to figure out which user is sending a message to the server.

Basically, though, this abuses the concept of PHP sessions. A PHP session is for a browser, not a browser tab/window.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Example added. You don't really need to use `$_SESSION['token']`, either -- you could just use the session's auto-generated ID if you wanted to. At the heart of it, it's the `instance` value that is making one browser window identify differently than another (since it is generated when the page is loaded without a POST request, and stays the same value so long as POSTs are being sent).

Comment: Cool thanks but what if I have page A opened with instance 0000001 and then page B with instance 0000002, but on submitter.php I cannot say which one has sent the commands, as $_SESSION[token] will be ovveriten by page B

Comment: It won't be. It first checks to see if a session token exists. It will *only* create a token if one hasn't already been created. Both browser windows will have the same session token, but they will be using a different instance number.